# CakePHP, issue with subfolder after creating virtualhost for domain name

Tags: apache, cakephp, subdirectory, virtual-server

I originally installed my cakephp in a subfolder of my localhost folder (so in linux my localhost is set to:

```
/var/www
```

and I installed cakephp to:

```
/var/www/site1
```

I had been using it at this address, so: http://localhost/site1

But now I am putting it up as a live site and I made a virtual server with apache so now this goes directly to the /site1 folder:

```
http://mydomainname.com/
```

Now I cannot access my cakephp site, it still seems to think it should be in the "site1" folder, I don't recall doing anything initially to tell it to be in the /site1 folder, such as setting anything, but it was a while ago and I can't remember exactly.. I am looking into this and the places it has told me to look so far where this info might be located is not showing anything indicating the subfolder.. I would greatly appreciate if anyone has ideas on what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Have you restarted apache since you made the change?

Comment: yes, I have, so now when I go to: "http://mydomainname.com/" it takes me to what previously was at: "http://mydomainname.com/site1" but then if I try to go to anything else, such as "http://mydomainname.com/controllername/functioname" (just exactly as before) it doesn't work, but did before I changed the virtual-server to go to the "site1" folder, when it would have been "http://mydomainname.com/site1/controllername/functioname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the `.htaccess` files have been copied into the right folders. If you haven't copied them, check they are there anyway.

Check over your `app/config/core.php` and `app/config/routes.php` to ensure that you don't have any path specific things in there.

Check your Apache vhost config to ensure that the document root is pointing to the folder you installed cake in. Such as `/site` and NOT to `site1/app/webroot` or anything like that.

*Afterthought,*
Check your Apache config to ensure that you are allowing local `htaccess` to override settings. And also make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server.

Also be sure to check over the full installation instructions, as there might be a tiny thing that you've missed which could contribute to your issue. http://book.cakephp.org/view/907/Developing-with-CakePHP